# load javascript in wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I found this great piece of code here: (http://jsfiddle.net/bzBzL/)
and I want to use it in my Wordpress page (I may need it on more than 1 page). I'm totally new to Javascript and Wordpress Codex doesn't help me much on this one. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)
Where to I need to insert the below code?
Thanks guys.
My website: www.visionmars.com

```
var timer, fullText, currentOffset, onComplete;

function Speak(person, text, callback) {
    $("#name").html(person);
    fullText = text;
    currentOffset = 0;
    onComplete = callback;
    timer = setInterval(onTick, 100);
}

function onTick() {
    currentOffset++;
    if (currentOffset == fullText.length) {
        complete();
        return;
    }
    var text = fullText.substring(0, currentOffset);
    $("#message").html(text);
}

function complete() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    $("#message").html(fullText);
    onComplete();
}

$(".box").click(function () {
    complete();
});

Speak("Simon",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",

function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
    Speak("Javascript", "Simon has finished speaking!");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Your jQuery code will not work with the jQuery shipped with WordPress. Please see the [documentation about the jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a JavaScript file and you can load it in functions.php like this:

```php
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Or in footer.php if your file is in the theme's root where the templates are, like this:

```php
<script src='<?php echo THEME_URL; ?>/your_js_file.js'></script>
```

The JavaScript file can be created anywhere in your theme root. You can make a folder and put the file there also.

Or if you want an admin way perspective you cand go to your Admin Panel to Appearence > Editor, here find footer.php and put your code between `<script></script>` just before the `</body>` closing tag. And it should load that script into all the pages of your website.

Also, a full documentation is here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script